# Commutative property in one object set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question, If we have $A=\{1\}$, Can I say it's commutative? it demands at least two different objects?

I think you can look at $(1,1)$ and say that $1+1$ is equal to $1+1$.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you say what is commutative?

Comment: It means that a+b is equal to b+a.

Comment: I think on a set with one element you can define one only (binary) operation and that ends to be commutative.

Comment: @Git Gud: sorry master, but what you mean with $+$ isn't strictly sum of reals/integers? Isn't the result of any binary operation $+$ or $\ast$ on $\left\{a\right\}$ equals to $a+a=a$?

Comment: @MattAllegro If I'm a master, you're in bad trouble :P. I made an assumption that $+$ denotes the usual $+$ and that $1$ denotes the usual $1\in \mathbb Z\subseteq \mathbb R$. The question isn't very clear to me.Your interpretation is another way to look at it.

Comment: I agree 100 percent the answer below by Seth. Nothing must be said more than that, being the set/element arbitrary.

Comment: @MattAllegro Me too, I misread the question and I abandon my previous interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

An set $A=\{x\}$ with one element has exactly one binary operation, the "identity" binary operation given by $x+x=x$.  So yes, with this operation $A$ is commutative.  Given any $a,b\in A$ we have $a=x,b=x$ so $a+b=x+x=b+a$.